# Selecting Word-Parts in C#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, richtextbox, textselection

While collecting some training data for NLP, I discovered that it is **impossible** to select parts of 2 adjacent words in a RichTextBox.

For example: you can not select "lect Me" from "Select Me" in a RichTextBox using mouse..!!

However it can be done using SHIFT key

Is there a property to be able to select parts of adjacent words not the whole words? That would make it easy for a human annotator...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RichTextBox has a property AutoWordSelection. When you set it to false, you get what you need.

Most probably, you will need to do it programmatically - for some reason changing it to false in Properties Tab did not help.

Comment: AutoWordSelection is to select all the word if any part of the -one- word is selected..

Comment: If you set this property to false, you can select just what you need - part of one word or parts of adjacent words. I've checked it.